# Appending content to every other div

Tags: jquery, html, append

This is simple but I got stuck and need some fresh mind for help.

What I want to achieve is to append content with jQuery to div. But to another div every other time, like this:

I have js now that it appends every 30 seconds content. HTML is like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

So every other time I would like it to add div b and every other time to div a.

Sorry for bad explanation.

Comment: do you have a changing number of elements? or is it gonna be always only a and b?

Comment: so what's your javascript? Can you also show it in your question?

Comment: At the moment its just a and b, but there could be changing numbers aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/ZT2Je/1/)**

```
setInterval(addDiv, 10000);
var aOrB = "a";

function addDiv() {
    $('#wrapper').append("<div class=" + aOrB + ">This is div with class " + aOrB + "</div>");
    if (aOrB === "a") aOrB = "b";
    else aOrB = "a";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure js version that cycle thought all divs in wrapper and add to its content. If you ever wanted to have more of those divs.

```
var divToAddTo = getElementById('warper').getElementsByTagName('div');
setInterval(function(){
    divToAddTo[i].innerHTML+="your content";
    i++;
    if(i=>divToAddTo.lenght){
        i=0;
    }
},30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var $wrapper = $('.wrapper');
var container1 = $('.wrapper .a');
var container2 = $('.wrapper .b');

setInterval(function(){

    var content = 'Hello, world!';

    var container = $wrapper.data('nextContainer');

    if(container == null)
         container = container1;

    container.append(content);

    $wrapper.data('nextContainer', container == container1 ? container2 : container1 );


}, 30 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` and `appendTo` functions to achieve this. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLN2z/). Check it out. Or if you have an `array` with fixed values, you can use it like this to use every `item` as a `class` of new `div`. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NhBzC/) for it.